# Why I can't set a vhost for this PHP website on my XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, vhosts

I am finding the following problem trying to create a **vhost** for a PHP website that I have into **XAMPP**.

So basically this is where is the **index.php** file of my website is deployed: **C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject-Panda**

Then into the C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf** file I have declared 2 vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/HotelRegistration/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/MyProject-Panda"
    ServerName panda.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

(the first one works fine, the second one no).

Finally into the **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** file I have:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       laravel.dev
127.0.0.1       panda.dev
```

So I am enabling the **panda.dev** domain on my local machine.

The problem is that when I open the **panda.dev** domain into my browser it is automatically "rewrited" into **http://www.panda.dev/** and it says that can't contact the server.

Why? What could be the problem? How can I try to solve this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.local` for local sites. `.dev` must not be interpreted correctly by browsers, even if you have hosts record.

In this case I think problem is - you have some `.htaceess` in `C:/xampp/htdocs/MyProject-Panda` with redirect to WWW version. Windows hosts does not work for subdomains automaticly (as www.panda.dev is subdomain of panda.dev). You eighter has to remove this redirection or add `127.0.0.1 www.panda.dev` record to your hosts file.